# kendo inline editing enable and disable fields

Tags: kendo-ui

How i can enable certain fields on add mode and disable on edit mode. I have add the following code but i unable to enable the description field on add mode. Please advise how I can achieve this?. Thank you

```
model.fields(p=> p.Description).Editable(false);
```

I want to enable description on add mode and disable on edit mode. THe following code is not working. Please advise if anything wrong with the code and if any other way to do it. THank you

```
function onEdit(e) {
    var indexCell = e.container.context.cellIndex;
    var grid = $('#BTSession').data('kendoGrid');


    if (!e.model.isNew()) { // when Editing
        if (indexCell != 'undefined' && grid.columns[indexCell].Title == "Description") {
                $('#BTSession').data("kendoGrid").closeCell();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two problems:

1. The `title` is lowercase. The check should be: `grid.columns[indexCell].title`
2. `isNew()` is always `false`. Alternatively you might check for `id` being `undefined` when you add a new record.

Something like:

```
function onEdit(e) {
    var indexCell = e.container.context.cellIndex;
    var grid = $('#BTSession').data('kendoGrid');


    if (e.model.id) { // when Editing the id is defined
        if (indexCell != 'undefined' && grid.columns[indexCell].title == "Description") {
            grid.closeCell();
        }
    }
}
```

**NOTE**: If in your model the `id` column is not called `id` (lets say `myId`) use the correct name.

**EDIT**: See a running example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/OnaBai/ehnSq/)

Comment: my model.ID = RefID therefore i put if(e.model.RefID).I received the following error: "Microsoft JScript runtime error: Unable to get value of the property 'title': object is null or "undefined

Comment: Which version of Kendo UI are you using?

Comment: I believe i used the following:Q2 2012 SP1

Comment: Please, check http://jsfiddle.net/OnaBai/ehnSq/. When create, you cannot edit _First name_ but you can while editing an existing record.

Comment: yes, i check your code but unfortunately still not working on site. Thank you

Comment: Is my code working in your browser or is your code the one not working?

Comment: Hi OnaBai, it is working. But i have to change my edit mode to InCell. Currently i need my edit mode is InLine. Any thought?